# Добавление картинки в ячейку Word из программы

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Есть код для вывода информации бд,которая находится в listView

```
        var allfields = Fields1Entities.GetContex().Fields.ToList();
       
        var application = new Word.Application();
        application.Visible = true;
        Word.Document document = application.Documents.Add();

        foreach(var field in allfields)
        {

            Word.Paragraph tableParagraph = document.Paragraphs.Add();
            Word.Range tableRange = tableParagraph.Range;
            Word.Table fieldsTable = document.Tables.Add(tableRange, allfields.Count() + 1, 8);
            fieldsTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = fieldsTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
            fieldsTable.Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
           
            Word.Range cellRange;

            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 1).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Картинка";
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 2).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Название";
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 3).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Местоположение";
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 4).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Год открытия";
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 5).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Возвраст";
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 6).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Условия эксплуатации";
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 7).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Запасы";
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(1, 8).Range;
            cellRange.Text = "Эксплуатируется/не эксплуатируется";

            fieldsTable.Rows[1].Range.Bold = 1;
            fieldsTable.Rows[1].Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;

            for(int i=0; i< allfields.Count(); i++)
            {
                var currentField = allfields[i];

                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 1).Range;

                Word.InlineShape imageShape = cellRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                   + "..\\..\\" + currentField.Picture);

                imageShape.Width = imageShape.Height = 40;
                cellRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            
            cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 2).Range;
                cellRange.Text = currentField.Name;

                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 3).Range;
                cellRange.Text = currentField.Location;

                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 4).Range;
                cellRange.Text = currentField.Year_of_study.ToString();

                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 5).Range;
                cellRange.Text = currentField.Age;

                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 6).Range;
                cellRange.Text = currentField.Conditions_of_exploitation;

                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 7).Range;
                cellRange.Text = currentField.Stocks;

                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 8).Range;
                cellRange.Text = currentField.DevelopNot;



            }
```

Проблема возникает на этой строчке, при добавлении в ячейку таблицы картинки

```
   Word.InlineShape imageShape = cellRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
               + "..\\..\\" + currentField.Picture);
```

Вылезает исключение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
                cellRange = fieldsTable.Cell(i + 2, 1).Range;

                var bit = currentField.Picture;
                
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bit))
                    {

                        BitmapImage img1 = new BitmapImage();
                        img1.BeginInit();
                        img1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        img1.StreamSource = ms;
                        img1.EndInit();
                        

                        Word.InlineShape imageShape = cellRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\", img1);


                    }



                    //imageShape.Width = imageShape.Height = 40;
                cellRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

Попробовала через bitmap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что такое `"..\\..\\"`? Вангую что надо так `cellRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\", currentField.Picture))`.

Comment: @aepot, у меня картинки хранятся в бд в виде byte, пишет,что несовпадение типа, байты с помощью bitmap перевела в изображение и добавила в строку, где выходит исключение, но всё равно не робит

Comment: Очевидно, ворд ждет путь к файлу на диске. Вы хоть понимаете разицу между путем к файлу и его содержимым. Внимательно ещё раз посмотрите, что вы вытворяете. Документацию откройте https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture

Comment: @aepot, с этим поняла, есть ещё проблемка, добавление записей происходит бесконечно(возможно потому что не прописала окончание операции), в гайдах в конце прописано сохранение файла в docx или pdf на диске, но у меня не даёт сохранить файл из-за места или других ограничений, можете ли вы подсказать какой-нибудь другой вариант)

Comment: Задайте другой вопрос, я не специалист по ворду.

Comment: у меня записи из программы по кругу добавляются в word, вы можете с этим помочь?

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture) - обратите внимание на типы, которые ожидает ворд, и на типы, которые вы ему передаете. "Несовпадение типа".

Надо записать файл на диск перед использованием. Передать путь ворду и затем удалить.

```
string path = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes(path, currentField.Picture);
Word.InlineShape imageShape = cellRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path);
// если сразу не удастся удалить временный файл, вдруг он будет занят,
// не забудьте его удалить после закрытия документа, иначе он останется на диске навсегда
File.Delete(path);
```